# How ctrl-d, ctrl-c is handled by C/scanf

Tags: c, escaping

Let's take the following program:

```
# include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int status, current_number, sum=0;
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    while(status=scanf("%d", &current_number)) {
        sum += current_number;
        printf("Status: %d. The current sum is: %d. Enter another number: ", status, sum);
    }   
}
```

> Enter a number: 2 
> Status: 1. The current sum is: 2. Enter another number: 3 
> Status: 1. The current sum is: 5. Enter another number: Status: -1. The current sum is: 8. Enter another number: ^C

It seems that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> (EOF) is recognized as `-1` but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> jus causes the program to quit. How are these two escape sequences usually handled in C? And why does `scanf` treat `ctrl-c` and `ctrl-d` differently?

Comment: Depends on the terminal. Typically `ctrl-d` sends the `EOF` character and `ctrl-c` sends a `SIGINT` signal. The default signal action for `SIGINT` is to terminate the program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `scanf` function does *not* treat these character in any special way, it doesn't even *see* those characters. What happens is that the terminal driver (at least under UNIX-like systems<sup>(a)</sup>) intercepts these keystrokes and translates them to special actions.

For <kbd>CTRL-d</kbd>, it closes the standard input file so that any code reading it will get an `EOF` - that's the `-1` you're seeing (indicating an error of some description on read).

For <kbd>CTRL-c</kbd>, it raises the `SIGINT` signal which, if uncaught, will terminate your program.

Keep in mind these are the *default* key-bindings for those actions, they can be changed with `stty` to use different ones. The default ones (`intr` and `eof`) are shown below (`^C` and `^D`):

```sh
pax> stty -a
speed 38400 baud; rows 37; columns 145; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>; eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z;
rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; discard = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd -cmspar cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff -iuclc -ixany -imaxbel -iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt echoctl echoke -flusho -extproc
```

---

And keep in mind this is probably *not* what you want:

```
while(status=scanf("%d", &current_number)) {
```

The loop will only exit when `scanf` returns zero, which will happen if an integer cannot be scanned (such as by entering the non-numeric `XYZZY`). It *will* continue for any non-zero value, *including* the `-1` you get back on error/end-of-file.

A better loop would be:

```
while((status = scanf("%d", &current_number)) == 1) {
```

In fact, since the loop should only *ever* run for a status value of `1`, it makes little sense to use it (other for a final decision on what happened). I'd prefer something like:

```c
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int stat, curr, sum = 0;

    // Prompt and loop while user enters valid numbers.

    printf("Enter a number: ");
    while ((stat = scanf("%d", &curr)) == 1) {
        // Accumulate number to sum, output details and ask for next.

        sum += curr;
        printf("Entered %d, sum is %d, enter another number: ", curr, sum);
    }

    // Final status -1 if EOF/error, 0 if item couldn't be scanned.

    if (stat == -1) {
        prinf("\nEnd of file or I/O error.\n");
    } else {
        prinf("Non-numeric data.\n");
    }
}
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Windows, from memory and by contrast, only recognises <kbd>CTRL-z</kbd> at the start of a line (and followed by <kbd>ENTER</kbd>) as the end-of-file indicator.